# How to auto adapt bottons's width that are on the same line in Android?

Tags: android, layout

It is possibile in Android to auto adapt bottons's width that are on the same line without write the specify width in the layout file?

I ask this question because with AppInvetor it is possibile to auto adapat bottons's width and this is the reason why i ask you this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) to do this. Just add the buttons to `TableRow`s and give them match_parent width

Answer (score 0):

One way is a table:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </TableRow>
<\TableLayout>
```

Alternatively, you can do a horizontal linear layout and assign a weight to each button with a width of 0.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<\LinearLayout>
```